# Cocoa popover without window

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm totally new in Cocoa development, and I wonder if it is possible to show popover at any position by hotkey. OS X dictionary app is very close to desired result. I want to show only popover, without window at cursor position. If it is possible, could you please provide some code for this popover?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did something like this for experimental purpose. The trick was to create a custom borderless window with transparent background or a zeroSize.

After creating, showing & positioning the window, the popover can be displayed from that.

For window creation: 
**Objective-C**

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
window.opaque = NO;
window.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
window.level = NSStatusWindowLevel;
window.accessibilityHidden = YES;
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
window = NSWindow(contentRect: windowRect, styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask, backing: .Buffered, defer: true)
window.opaque = false
window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.StatusWindowLevelKey))
window.setAccessibilityHidden(true)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
```

And for the popover:
**Objective-C**

```
//Create popover .........
[popover showRelativeToRect:popoverRect ofView:window.contentView preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

**Swift**

```
//Create popover ......
popover.showRelativeToRect(popoverRect, ofView: window.contentView, preferredEdge: .MaxY)
```

In order to dismiss the popover when clicking somewhere on screen, a global event monitor has to be added:

**Objective-C**

```
//Add global monitor to track when the popover should be closed
if (self.monitor == nil) {
    self.monitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSKeyUpMask) handler:^(NSEvent* event) {
        [NSEvent removeMonitor:self.monitor];
        self.monitor = nil;
        [self.popover close];
        self.window = nil;
    }];
}
```

**Swift**

```
if monitor == nil {
     monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask([.LeftMouseDownMask, .RightMouseDownMask /* and others like keyDown/Up if you want*/], handler: { (event: NSEvent) in
        NSEvent.removeMonitor(monitor!)
        monitor = nil
        popover.close()
        window = nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I want, except that I want to close this popover when user clicks outside of it (e.g., popover lost focus). I will try to figure out by myself, but any hints are appreciated. I got answer to my primary question: It's possible to create popover without visible window IN GENERAL.

Comment: Ah I just forgot to add this code (was quite late yesterday) will add it later

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to see how to set focus on popover, regardless of it's content (I will probably want to display only NSLabel there, not any kind of input widgets).

Comment: Wow, such a creative way